# How to make a range series in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to improve a Stored Procedure, it uses a `select` query on a table as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ProjectId FROM Project where Status ='P' Order by ProjectId
```

it give an output as follows:

```
1
2
3
7
8
11
12
13
```

I need to use these values in insert statement for another table as follow:

```
insert into Table values (othervalue, 1|1);
insert into Table values (othervalue, 2|2);
....
```

To decrease the number of inserts, we want to store as follows:

```
insert into Table values (othervalue, 1|3);
insert into Table values (othervalue, 7|8);
insert into Table values (othervalue, 11|13);
```

That is in range till the time there is no gap. I tried using `CURSOR` to loop through the resultset and have some logic to convert it and keep on inserting. But seems some error.

Can we do something in `SELECT`query itself?

Comment: Don't do this. It's not good table design, and will hurt performance in the long run more than it helps, as you start needing to do inequality comparisions ( <, > ) to get data back out. Just do the inserts.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, Thank you for your suggestion. But this is just one time load process and the data is picked up from this table as Select ALL, and inequality comparisons etc. is done in the Java program. So, less number of rows is good for our Java code to handle it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t(a,en,bg) as
(
select a,case when [begin] is NULL then NULL else row_number() over(partition by [begin] order by a) end
,case when [end] is NULL then NULL else row_number() over(partition by [end] order by a) end
 from (
select t.a, case when t1.a is NULL then 'end' else NULL end [end], 
case when t2.a is NULL then 'begin' else NULL end [begin] 
 from  Project as t left join  Project as t1 on (t1.a=t.a+1 AND t.Status='P' AND t1.Status='P')
left join Project as t2 on (t2.a=t.a-1 AND t2.Status='P')
) as o ) 
select cast(t1.a as varchar)+'|'+cast(t.a as varchar) from t inner join t as t1 on t.en=t1.bg
```

This query will return you values from Project in '1|3' type.

It's not clear from your question whether you use plsql or sql-server. My solution will be work for MS SQL Server

Comment: Thank you but It seems, the query is still not considering the condition `where Status ='P'` as it returns the sequence for all ids.

Comment: build the SQL Fiddle so I can check this query on your data

Comment: I made it work with slight modifications taking your query as base. It was indeed helpful. Thank you!!